# Jest - Access function in Antd form.validate after a submit

Tags: forms, jestjs, enzyme, antd

I want to test that a function I passed by props is called after a submit and a Antd form.validateFields.
After looking I have already tried expect(myfunction).toHaveBeenCalled(), but it didn't work.
It does work if my function is outside the scope of form.validateFields but not if inside.

Here is the extract of the code of the class describing the Form + the submit function.

```js
export class SettingsMasterbot extends React.Component<ISettingsMasterbotProps, ISettingsMasterbotState> {

    constructor(props:  ISettingsMasterbotProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event : React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
    // this is seen as called
            this.props.changeMasterbotParameters({
                name: '',
                greetingMessages: [''],
                disambiguationMessages: [''],
                avatar: '',
                rgpd: {nbofDays: 90}
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('error :',e)
        }
        this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('Received values of form: ', values); // this shows in console

                try {
                    //this is not seen as called by test (test FAILS)
                    this.props.changeMasterbotParameters({
                        name: values.name,
                        greetingMessages: values.greetingMessages,
                        disambiguationMessages: values.disambiguationMessages,
                        avatar: '',
                        rgpd: {nbofDays: values.rgpdNbOfDays}
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error('error:',e) // this doesn't show in console
                }

            } else {
                // There has been an error, Antd form validation
                message.warning('Oh no ! Some entries are missing !');
            }
        });
    };


    render() {
        const {getFieldDecorator} = this.props.form;

        return (
            <div>
                <Form layout={"vertical"} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Header
                        style={{
                            padding: 0
                        }}
                    >
                        <PageHeader
                            title={""}
                            ghost={false}
                            extra={[
                                <Button
                                    type="primary"
                                    htmlType="submit"
                                    shape="circle"
                                    className="saveMasterbotParameters-btn"
                                    icon="save"
                                    size={"default"}
                                    key={"masterbotSettingsButton"}/>
                            ]}
    ....
```

And this is the test I am trying to deal with :

```js
describe('>>> Settings Masterbot --- ANTD Form Unit Tests', () => {
    let wrapper: ReactWrapper;
    let accountSettings = mockupInitialState.accountSettings;
    let systemSettings = mockupInitialState.systemSettings;
    const wrapperForm = shallow(<SettingsMasterbotFormWrapper/>);
    // const component:ReactWrapper = mount(<div>wrapperForm.find(SettingsMasterbot)</div>);
    const component = wrapperForm.find(SettingsMasterbot);
    const form = component.props().form;
    const props = {
        accountSettings: accountSettings,
        systemSettings: systemSettings,
        changeMasterbotParameters: jest.fn(), //the function is mocked
        form: form
    };

    beforeAll(() => {
        wrapper = mount(<SettingsMasterbot {...props} />) // the reason of beforeAll is because of some components used in the react class have weird behavior (builds themselves several time if I beforeEach).
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

   it('+++ check saveMasterbotParameters function is called when clicking on save', () => {
        // wrapper.find('.ant-btn.saveMasterbotParameters-btn').simulate('submit', { preventDefault: ()=> {jest.fn()}});
        wrapper.find(Form).simulate('submit', { preventDefault: ()=> {jest.fn()}});
        expect(props.changeMasterbotParameters).toHaveBeenCalled(); // THIS FAILS
//FYI
        expect(wrapper.find(SettingsMasterbot).prop('changeMasterbotParameters')).toEqual(props.changeMasterbotParameters)
        // This Passes, so the props are well passed.
    });
```

Any clues/advice are welcome... I feel it is right in front of me but can't see it.
Feel free to ask questions, I'll edit along the way.